# How to assign a return to a pre element?

Tags: javascript, pre

I am trying to figure out how to assign a generated CSS to a pre element. I want to final results to be a simple CSS code inside a pre element. Similar to what I shared inside the console.log. Can anyone help and explain what am I doing wrong?

```js
 function generate(columnStartName, columnEndName) {
          columnStartName = document.getElementById("start").value;
          columnEndName = document.getElementById("end").value;
        
          let columnStartStyles = ''
          let columnEndStyles = ''
          
          for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
              columnStartStyles+=`div[class~="${columnStartName}${i}"] {grid-column-start: ${i};}
      `
              columnEndStyles+=`div[class~="${columnEndName}${i}"] {grid-column-end: ${i+1};}
      `
          }
            let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
            pre.textContent = generate;


          // console.log
          // `/* Grid system */
          // grid, .grid {
          //   display: grid;
          //   grid-template-columns: var(--grid-tc-12);
          //   grid-column-gap: var(--grid-gap);
          //   grid-row-gap: var(--grid-gap);
          //   align-content: stretch;
          //   align-self: stretch;
          // }
          
          // grid > div {
          //   align-self: start;
          // }
          // ${columnStartStyles}
          // ${columnEndStyles}
          // `
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="start" type=text value="start"> 

  <br><br>
  <input id="end" type=text value="end">

  <br><br>
  <INPUT TYPE=button VALUE="Generate CSS"  onClick="generate();">

 </form>

<div id="msg">
 <pre></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: `pre.textContent = generate;` <= I'm confused by this.  `generate` is the name of a method

Comment: hmm what should I add in order to show the result inside the pre? like in the console.log?

Comment: Well, take a step back for a second and think about this.  You are doing stuff to `columnStartStyles` and `columnEndStyles`, but you never use them.  Why is that?  Why do you have those variables?  What did you intend for them to be used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do the following:

Get rid of the space at the end of the template.
use \n for new lines
For the textContent line, use `columnEndStyles` and `columnStartStyles` instead.

```js
function generate(columnStartName, columnEndName) {
          columnStartName = document.getElementById("start").value;
          columnEndName = document.getElementById("end").value;
        
          let columnStartStyles = ''
          let columnEndStyles = ''
          
          for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
              columnStartStyles+=`div[class~="${columnStartName}${i}"] {\n  grid-column-start: ${i};\r\n}\n\n`
              columnEndStyles+=`div[class~="${columnEndName}${i}"] {\n  grid-column-end: ${i+1};\r\n}\n\n`
          }
            let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
            pre.textContent = columnStartStyles + columnEndStyles;


          // console.log
          // `/* Grid system */
          // grid, .grid {
          //   display: grid;
          //   grid-template-columns: var(--grid-tc-12);
          //   grid-column-gap: var(--grid-gap);
          //   grid-row-gap: var(--grid-gap);
          //   align-content: stretch;
          //   align-self: stretch;
          // }
          
          // grid > div {
          //   align-self: start;
          // }
          // ${columnStartStyles}
          // ${columnEndStyles}
          // `
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="start" type=text value="start"> 

  <br><br>
  <input id="end" type=text value="end">

  <br><br>
  <INPUT TYPE=button VALUE="Generate CSS"  onClick="generate();">

 </form>

<div id="msg">
 <pre></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, what should I add to get also the too? 
/* Grid system */
          grid, .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: var(--grid-tc-12);
            grid-column-gap: var(--grid-gap);
            grid-row-gap: var(--grid-gap);
            align-content: stretch;
            align-self: stretch;
          }
          
          grid > div {
            align-self: start;
          }